# Facebook Publish_Action Submission Failed (No api call 30 days)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

[image]

I am unable to submit my application for review because of this message.
But I have made so many api calls by api explorer facebook. even i test with test users ... Your help will be highly appreciated on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a current open bug report for this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/267332513657684/

Suggest you go and subscribe to it (bug reports are prioritized by the number of affected apps/developers), and perhaps mention your app id in the comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you made the API calls in the API Explorer with the "API Explorer App", and not with your own one. You need to use/test the permission directly in your App, and NOT in the API Explorer. That´s where Facebook will test it too.

Comment: Anyone know the answer

Comment: in that case, see the bug report